# Find the longest sublist

Tags: perl, shell, awk, grep, wc

I have a file containing list and sublist and I want to extract the longest sublist using command line tools.

File example:

```
* Item1
** SubItem1
** ...
** SubItemN

* Item2
** SubItem1
** ...
** SubItemN

* ...
** ...

* ItemN
** SubItem1
** ...
** SubItemN
```

I am trying to know if this can be done easily, otherwise I will write a Perl script.

Comment: Easier than a Perl script? I don't think so. Sounds like about 2-3 lines of Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Perl one-liner:

```
perl -00 -ne '$n=tr/\n/\n/; if ($n>$m) {$m=$n; $max=$_}; END {print $max}' file
```

Just using bash:

```
max=0
while read bullet thingy; do
    case $bullet in
         "*") item=$thingy; count=0 ;;
        "**") ((count++)) ;;
          "") (( count > max )) && { max_item=$item; max=$count; } ;; 
    esac
done < <(cat file; echo)
echo $max_item $max
```

The `<(cat file; echo)` part is to ensure that there is a blank line after the last line of the file, so that the last sublist group can be compared against the max

That only keeps the count. To save the items in the biggest sublist:

```
max=0
while read bullet thingy; do
    case $bullet in
         "*") item=$thingy; unset sublist; sublist=() ;;
        "**") sublist+=($thingy) ;;
          "") if (( ${#sublist[@]} > max )); then
                  max=${#sublist[@]}
                  max_item=$item
                  max_sublist=("${sublist[@]}")
              fi
              ;;
    esac
done < <(cat file; echo)
printf "%s\n" "$max_item" "${#max_sublist[@]}" "${max_sublist[@]}"
```

if using sudo_O's example, this outputs

```
letters
6
a
b
b
d
e
f
```

Comment: it reads the file one paragraph at a time ([`-00`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)) -- storing each paragraph in the special variable [`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables). It counts the number of newlines in the paragraph ([`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html)). The rest, finding the max, should be pretty obvious.

Comment: @JohnJohnGa, I added some links in my comment for further edification

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file    
* letters
** a
** b
** b
** d
** e
** f

* colors 
** red
** green
** blue

* numbers
** 1
** 2
** 3
** 4
** 5
```

Show length of each sublist by reversing file with `tac` and using `awk`:

```
$ tac file | awk '/^\*\*/{c++}/^\*[^*]/{print c,$2;c=0}'
5 numbers
3 colors
6 letters
```

Print length of largest sublist only:

```
$ tac file | awk '/^\*\*/{c++}/^\*[^*]/{if(c>m){m=c;l=$2}c=0}END{print m,l}'
6 letters
```

Comment: awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (syntax error ^* or ^+)
^*[^*]

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt | grep -nE "^\*[^\*].*" | cut -d ":" -f 1,1 | tee tmp | awk 'NR==1{s=$1;next}    {print $1-s;s=$1}' > tmp2
echo 0 >> tmp2
res=`paste tmp tmp2 | sort -nrk 2,2 | head -n 1`
line=`echo "$res" | cut -f 1,1`
ln=`echo "$res" | cut -f 2,2`
cat file.txt | tail -n +$line | head -n $ln
rm tmp tmp2
```

There is definitely a shorter solution :)